# get the form values on the same page after submit the the form in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

i have one form that form is open in popup..so i have only 2 fields in that form..after i submit the form i want to display the form values on the same popup(below the form).how can i do that..can any one help me..

here is my vue page:

```
<el-form :model="ScheduleInterviewForm" :rules="rules" ref="ScheduleInterviewForm" :inline="true">
            <el-form-item prop="schedule_datetime">
              <el-date-picker
                  v-model="ScheduleInterviewForm.schedule_datetime"
                  type="datetime"
                  size="small"
                  placeholder="Select Interview date">

              </el-date-picker>
            </el-form-item>

            <el-form-item prop="interview_type_id">
              <el-select size="small" v-model="ScheduleInterviewForm.interview_type_id" placeholder="Select Interview Type">
                <el-option
                  v-for="it in interview_types"
                  :label="it.type"
                  :value="it.id">
                </el-option>
              </el-select>
            </el-form-item>

            <ElButton
              type="success"
              size="small"
              @click="ScheduleInterview('ScheduleInterviewForm', c.hrc_id)">
              SCHEDULE INTERVIEW
            </ElButton>
    </el-form>

        <el-alert
          v-show="interviewScheduled"
          title="INTERVIEW SCHEDULED!"
          type="success">
        </el-alert>

         <el-form :model="ScheduleInterviewForm" :rules="rules" ref="ScheduleInterviewForm" :inline="true">
            <el-form-item prop="schedule_datetime">
            </el-form-item>
       </el-form>

export default {
props: ['c', 'interview_types'],
data() {
    return {
        ResumeDialog: false,
        ScheduleInterviewForm: {
            schedule_datetime: null,
            interview_type_id: null,
        },
        rules: {
          schedule_datetime: [
            { type: 'date', required: true, message: 'Select Schedule time', trigger: 'blur' },
            { validator: isDateFuture, trigger: 'blur' },
          ],
          interview_type_id: [
            { type: 'number', required: true, message: 'Select Interview type', trigger: 'blur' }
          ],
        },
        interviewScheduled: null,
    }
},
methods: {
  ScheduleInterview(form, hrcId) {
    var that = this;
    this.$refs[form].validate((valid) => {
      if (valid) {
        // AJAX: Create HrRequest
        axios.post('/ajax/schedule_interview', {
          interviewTypeId: this.ScheduleInterviewForm.interview_type_id,
          scheduleDatetime: this.ScheduleInterviewForm.schedule_datetime,
          hrcId
        })
        .then(function(res) {
             that.interviewScheduled = true;

          setTimeout(() => that.interviewScheduled = false, 3000);
          console.log(res);
          // that.candidates = res.data.candidates;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  },
},
components: { ElButton, ElDialog, ElCard },
```

}

here is my js page:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: () => ({
    hr_request: window.data.hr_request,
    candidates: window.data.candidates,
    interview_types: window.data.interview_types,

}),
methods: {
    ScheduleInterview(requestCandidateId, interviewTime) {
        console.log(requestCandidateId, interviewTime);
    },
},
components: {
    Candidate,
    Schedule,
}
```

});

Please can any one help me..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the inputed values in the form show up af

ter the form is successfully submitted

1. Add a property in your data property as below:

   ```
   data(){
               return{
                   showFormValues = false;
               }
           }
   ```
2. Add a div with the inputed values in paragraph tags below the form and show the div only if form is sucessfully sunbmitted usimg `v-show` as below:

   ```
   <div v-show="showFormValues">
       <p>date: {{ScheduleInterviewForm.schedule_datetime}}</p>
       <p>type: {{ScheduleInterviewForm.interview_type_id}}</p>
   </div>
   ```
3. Now in the **success** part **then** block of your form submittion click method set the value of `showFormValues = true` like this:

   ```
   ScheduleInterview(form, hrcId) {
       var that = this;
       this.$refs[form].validate((valid) => {
         if (valid) {
           // AJAX: Create HrRequest
           axios.post('/ajax/schedule_interview', {
             interviewTypeId: this.ScheduleInterviewForm.interview_type_id,
             scheduleDatetime: this.ScheduleInterviewForm.schedule_datetime,
             hrcId
           })
           .then(function(res) {
                that.interviewScheduled = true;
              //show the input form values on succesful form submission
                that.showFormValues = true;
             setTimeout(() => that.interviewScheduled = false, 3000);
             console.log(res);
             // that.candidates = res.data.candidates;
           })
           .catch(function(err) {
             console.log(err);
           });
         } else {
           return false;
         }
       });
     },
   ```

Comment: <div v-show="showFormValues">
    <p>date: {{ScheduleInterviewForm.schedule_datetime}}</p>
    <p>type: {{ScheduleInterviewForm.interview_type_id}}</p>
</div>  where i ahve to add this with in the template or outside the template

Comment: @bharathi inside the template below the form in the modal where you want to display it. By the way you are asking inside or outside the template...you cant write html code outside the template tag

Comment: i have another doubt..after submit the form my form values dosen't disappear..it stays there only..i want to remove the form values..after submit..and if user enter another details it just edit the before values instead of creating new row..

Comment: after submit the values are appearing..and then i close the popup..and i refresh the page..the values are disappearing..i want those values should be there only..

Comment: can you please explain me..i am trying to do this..from past 6 hours..it's not working..

Comment: @bharathi what exactly do you want, i will help you, dont worry

Comment: oh thank you..after submit the form it showing the values below the form..so that is fine..then after i close the popup..and i refresh the page..the values disappeared..

Comment: @bharathi when you refresh the page vue re-renders the component which means it also reseta the objects in you data property back to intial state, if you rally want to save those values then try to persist them by saving in cookies or localstorage

Comment: how to do that..i have no idea on that one..if it is possible can you please explain me..

Comment: @bharathi its difficult to explain here, suggest any other idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144441/discussion-between-bharathi-and-user7814783).

Comment: i have one doubt..if you are free...can you please explain me

Comment: actually i am trying to reset passsword but its not storing token in db in php